# How to run phonegap using php?

Tags: php, android, cordova, command-line-interface

how to run phonegap cli using php scripts?
i can manually run phonegap with windows cmd and everything works great but when i call ex:'phonegap build android' in php exec, nothing happens. no error no catch block, nothing.

here is my code:

test.php

```
<?php
$out = array();
try {
    $create_command = 'phonegap create test';
    $build_command = 'phonegap build android';
    exec($build_command,$out);
    foreach($out as $line) echo $line.'<br>';
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

by the way i registered php in environments then ran 'php %path_to_file%/test.php' in cmd and it worked.

Comment: Well, `$out` is empty, `$create_command` is never used, and nothing in your code throws an exception... maybe you should think a little more about your code? I suggest you look up [`exec()` in the documentation](http://php.net/exec).

Comment: sry yep your right about $out, i forgot to write it here. its like `exec($build_command,$out)` in real file as manual. and that's not matter that $create_command is never used. the point is none of phonegap commands work when i load test.php with browser and webserver. thanks for your reply

Comment: @monias this might be cause by lack of permissions.
but just to be sure please run this:
    $build_command = 'phonegap build android 2>&1';
on exec to atleast see the errors.

Comment: Did you try enabling PHP errors? This typically helps to find out failures like that... You're not on a shared hosting right? You're trying this locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks for your replies. but there was nothing  wrong with my codes. problem was fast-cgi which is not installed by default on xampp. i changed my web server to nginx using this web server [WT-NMP](http://wtriple.com/wtnmp/?wtSrc=exe).

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
<?php
function sys_cmd($cmd)
{   
    $hd = popen($cmd,"r") or die('function disabled');
    while (!feof($hd))
    {
        $rs .= fread($hd,1024);     
    }
    pclose($hd);
    return $rs;
}

out = array();
try {
    $create_command = 'phonegap create test';
    $build_command = 'phonegap build android';

    sys_cmd ($build_command, $out);

    foreach($out as $line){
        echo $line.'<br>';
    }
}

catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
exec($build_command,$out);<br>
foreach($out as $line) echo $line.'<br>';
```

by this:

```
passthru( $build_command );
```

The [passthru](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) command does the same as exec and writes the resulting code directly to the browser.

Comment: could u add more detail : needed php modules , security settings and etc , for example this doesn't work on xampp, why ?

Comment: I tested it with Xampp, no problems with it. Create a text file called test.txt with the contents you want. Now create a test.php with this content <?php passthru( 'cmd /c type test.txt'); ?> You should see the contents of the text file on the browser.

Comment: sure it work but problem was fast cgi , by default xampp safemode allow limited windows commands not phonegap

Comment: Ok, nice to see you fixed it. Regards,